# TFS 2018: Creating customState Types to be displayed in board view

Tags: tfs

I am needing some help on creating custom types for a custom state.

I have created the custom State already using one of the built-in "InProgress" types, but would love to create a new type "ReadytoDeploy" state.

I have attached a screenshot of the process configuration with my new "Ready to Deploy" state with the type value highlighted.
[XML configuration screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZyoN.png)

What I am wanting to achieve is the custom state to be displayed in the summaries on the collapsed board view.
There are quite a few items in below screenshot which are set to the "Ready to Deploy" state, but the summary includes them in the "XX In Progress" summary.
[board view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9G9xF.png)

I have done a lot of hunting around the various XML files, and can't seem to find where these State Types are defined.

If it makes a difference, we are using the Agile process by default.

I did some reading on the MS TFS raticles, and eventually found this section which lists all the built-in State Types, but no mention of how to create custom entries
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/process-configuration-xml-element?view=azure-devops-2022#syntax-for-states-elements-wit-category

Thanks,
Angus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For XML process, customizing State Type (State Category) is not supported. See "[**Supported customizations**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/on-premises-xml-process-model?view=tfs-2018#supported-customizations)".

Same limitation is also for Inherited process.

If your projects really need this feature, I recommend you try to report a feature request on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOpsServerTFS/suggest). That will make it more convenient for the product teams to receive and understand your ideas. And your feedback also could be helpful for improving our Azure DevOps products.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up.

Given the complete lack of info, and me not being able to find the settings in any XML files, that was my assumption.
It's not that big a deal I guess, just would be nice,